# <olcRootPW> can only be set when rootdn is under suffix

Tags: ldap, openldap

can someone help me to resolve this error?

```
5c18d91d ldif_read_file: checksum error on "/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config.ldif"
5c18d91d olcRootPW: value #0: <olcRootPW> can only be set when rootdn is under suffix
5c18d91d config error processing cn=config: <olcRootPW> can only be set when rootdn is under suffix
slaptest: bad configuration file!
```

my `olcDatabase\=\{2\}hdb.ldif` is :

```
dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcHdbConfig
olcDatabase: {2}hdb
olcDbDirectory: /var/lib/ldap
olcRootDN: cn=admin,dc=10.6.113.60
olcSuffix: dc=10.6.113.60
olcDbIndex: objectClass eq,pres
olcDbIndex: ou,cn,mail,surname,givenname eq,pres,sub
structuralObjectClass: olcHdbConfig
entryUUID: cd57a4aa-85c3-1038-887e-196d6c686da6
creatorsName: cn=config
createTimestamp: 20181126123738Z
entryCSN: 20181126123738.098670Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=config
modifyTimestamp: 20181126123738Z
```

Answer (score 1):

You've hand-edited the LDIF file which is your first error, even though each of those files has a warning at the top of them saying not to do that.

The second error is telling you that the root DN needs to a) be set to something and that b) it's under the suffix of the database which is `cn=config`, for example, `cn=manager,cn=config`.

I suspect you've set the password manually in `/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config.ldif` which is what caused both errors.

Comment: my olcDatabase\=\{2\}hdb.ldif is : 
dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcHdbConfig
olcDatabase: {2}hdb
olcDbDirectory: /var/lib/ldap
olcRootDN: cn=admin,dc=10.6.113.60
olcSuffix: dc=10.6.113.60
olcDbIndex: objectClass eq,pres
olcDbIndex: ou,cn,mail,surname,givenname eq,pres,sub
structuralObjectClass: olcHdbConfig
entryUUID: cd57a4aa-85c3-1038-887e-196d6c686da6
creatorsName: cn=config
createTimestamp: 20181126123738Z
entryCSN: 20181126123738.098670Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=config
modifyTimestamp: 20181126123738Z

Comment: I don't see how that is related; that's not where the error is coming from. It doesn't contain any `olcRootPW` attributes.